# Anaconda Navigator installing an older version (0.7.3) of Sympy

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm new to Python and just downloaded Anaconda Python.  Anaconda comes with Sympy 1.4 but I need to use Sympy 0.7.3.

I see that Anaconda Navigator has the option to replace 1.4 with other versions (specifically 1.1.1 or 1.2 or 1.3) however 0.7.3 is not in the list.  I have found an archive with version 0.7.3 at https://anaconda.org/anaconda/sympy/files?version=0.7.3 and I tried adding that path to the channel list but it was flagged as an invalid channel.  How do I import Sympy 0.7.3?

I'm running on Windows and am doing all this because I want to run Symoro.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Anaconda recently dropped support](https://www.anaconda.com/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7/) for what was called their **free** channel and this has resulted in many older packages becoming inaccessible by default. Unfortunately, that older version of SymPy is in that part of the repository.  You have two options:

1. Download the tarball and install from that.
2. Enable access to the **free** channel.

**SymPy 0.7.3 is only available for Python 2.6, 2.7, or 3.3**.  If you want to use Python 2.7 then downloading should be the easiest route; for Python 3.3 (or 2.6 for some reason), I'd recommend the latter option, because almost all the other packages for these versions are also in the **free** channel.

In either case, you will use Anaconda Prompt (or another shell) and need to create a new environment, because it is generally a bad idea to force major changes into the Anaconda **base** environment.

---

## Option 1: Installing from the Tarball

1. First, you need create the new Python 2.7 env. Let's call it `my_env`:

   ```
   conda create --name my_env python=2.7
   ```

   If there is other software you know you'll want, then you can also include that after the `python=2.7`.
2. Download [the file `sympy-0.7.3-py27_0.tar.bz2`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/sympy/0.7.3/download/win-64/sympy-0.7.3-py27_0.tar.bz2) (this is the **win-64** version - others are [where you pointed out already](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/sympy/files?version=0.7.3)).
3. Install it:

   ```
   conda install -n my_env sympy-0.7.3-py27_0.tar.bz2
   ```
4. Test your new env:

   ```
   conda activate my_env
   python -c "import sympy; sympy.doctest('polynomial')"
   ```

---

## Option 2: (Temporarily) Enabling the **free** Channel

Just note that I wouldn't generally recommend keeping this enabled since it really tends to slow down the Conda solver (see "[*Why we removed the free channel in Conda 4.7*](https://www.anaconda.com/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7/)).  I'll recommend disabling it again (step 3), but keep in mind that if you ever need to make adjustments to your SymPy 0.7.3 env, you'll probably need to re-enable it.

1. Enable the **free** channel:

   ```
   conda config --set restore_free_channel True
   ```
2. Create your new env:

   ```
   conda create --name my_env python=3.3 sympy=0.7.3
   ```
3. Disable **free** channel

   ```
   conda config --set restore_free_channel False
   ```
4. Test your SymPy env

   ```
   conda activate my_env
   python -c "import sympy; sympy.doctest('polynomial')"
   ```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 so I tried option 1 and it worked perfectly!  Thank you!

Comment: @LynnTinney if you have Python 2.7 as your **base**, then I guess that's the one case where you wouldn't need to make a new env. Anyway, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [installing packages on anaconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages)

> To install a specific version of a package such as SciPy:
>
> `conda install scipy=0.15.0`

So try

```
conda install sympy=0.7.3
```

Seems to do the trick for me. It's in the default conda channel so you shouldn't need to change or add a channel

Comment: This works for you because you're running a pre-4.7 version of `conda`.

Comment: Yes, as merv pointed out, when I tried to do that with my recently downloaded version of Anaconda, I got a message saying that "the package is not available from current channels"